# Xscreensaver error xubuntu

Tags: 14.04, graphics, xubuntu, shutdown, screensaver

- When idle, instead of seeing screensavers, i got an error related to xscreensaver, i don't know what exactly, i'll take a picture of it soon and update the question
- When Idle, I move the mouse to continue working, I see

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9dz8.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT2rq.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/klKOu.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj6Iy.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aNgd.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there's an error with xscreensaver. I believe you hit [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xscreensaver/+bug/637676), although there doesn't seem to be a solution.

Try to disable or uninstall xscreensaver.

Can you please edit your question and elaborate on what the last 2 screenshots and "fallback mode" have to do with that?

Comment: ok I'll split it into 2 questions